# Talend tExtractXMLField

Tags: java, xml, xpath, talend

I have this job in Talend that is supposed to retrieve a field and loop through it.

My big problem is that the code is looping through the XML fields but it's returning null. 
Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<empresas>
    <empresa>
        <imoveis>
            <imovel>
                [-- some fields --  ]

                <fotos>
                    <nome id="" order="">photo1</nome>
                    <nome id="" order=""></nome>
                    <nome id="" order=""></nome>
                    <nome id="" order=""></nome>
                </fotos>
            </imovel>
            [ -- other entries here -- ]
        </imoveis>
    </empresa>
</empresas>
```

Now using the tExtractXMLField component I am trying to get the "fotos" element.
Here is what I have in the component:
[image]

I have tried to change the XPath query and the XPath loop query but the result is either I don't loop through the field or I get the null in the value field in the tMap.

Here is an image of the job:

[image]

You can see that I have retrieved 4 items from the XML but what I get is null in the "nome" field. There must be something wrong with the XPath but I can't seem to find the problem :(

Hope someone can help me out. Thanks
Notes: I am using talendv4.1.2 on ubuntu 10.10 64bit

Answer (score 7):

If you want to loop on `<nome>` nodes your Loop XPath Query has to be

```
"/empresas/empresa/imoveis/imovel/fotos/nome"
```

and foto_nome XPath Query something like

```
"text()"
```

Take care: I also corrected an error in your XML that could bring issues (`</imoveis>` missing the "s").

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about it. One way is to use directly XMLinput and the instructions that **bluish** mentioned.

The other way is to continue on the path that you chose. In the XMLinput, make sure that your Loop XPath query is set to `"/empresas/empresa/imoveis/imovel/fotos"` and that you pass through the *fotos* element with the *Get Nodes* option checked. The XPath Query of your *fotos* element should be `"../fotos"` or `"."`.

Your extractXMLField component looks to be well configured.
Also, I don't know what tSetGlobalVar does in your design, but make sure it doesn't affect the *fotos* element that you're trying to pass through.

Answer (score 1):

[image: sample talend job]
I have made a test job, this will help you definitely. If I'm not wrong you want to get all the "nome" under the "fotos" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your loop xpath to the top level in the file, "empresas". Sometimes that works for me, also I have seem the "?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?" tag cause problems before, you could try to remove that.

Also make sure that the encoding is set correctly in the tFileInputXML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing reading XML and extracting XML from XML.

Reading XML:
If the part of XML you have provided is the file readed by you tFileInputXML you don't need tExtractXMLField, just configure the tFileInputXML as this:

- set the xpath loop to the `<nome>` elements, like this "//nome"
- add 3 columns in the tFileInputXML component id, order and content
- get content column with xpath query "."
- get id value with xpath query "@id"
- get order value with xpath query "@order"

[image]

Extracting XML from XML:
That is the goal of the tExtractXMLField component:
It allows to parse XML data contained in a database column or another XML document as if it was itself a data flow.

To put it in a nutshell, tExtractXMLField create a flow of data from a column record containing XML.
It is very useful when parsing soap query result: server reply is usually provided as xml, like this one:

```
<arg2> 
  <![CDATA[
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <exportInscriptionEnLigneType>
      <date>2015-04-10</date>
      <nbDossiers>2</nbDossiers>
      <reference>20150410100</reference>
      <listeDossiers>
        <dossier>
          <numOrdre>1</numOrdre>
          <identifiantDossier>AAAAA</identifiantDossier>
        </dossier>
        <dossier>
          <numOrdre>2</numOrdre>
          <identifiantDossier>BBBBB</identifiantDossier>
        </dossier>
      </listeDossiers>
    </exportInscriptionEnLigneType>
]]>
</arg2>
```

In XML above, arg2>element contains an XML document that you may need to parse.

tExtractXMLField has been created for this purpose.
I've written a tutorial on how to achieve this work, please have a look here "[how to extract xml from xml](http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2015/talend-extract-xml-from-xml/extraire-un-fichier-xml-contenu-dan-un-autre-fichier-xml)". It is in french but screenshots may help understanding the few comments provided.

Hope it will help.

Best regards,